# JQuery .load() issues

Tags: jquery, function, variables, load

```
var img = $('.container img');

$(img).load(function () { 
   // do something
});
```

I am having an issue with the `.load()` function. This is a snippet of my code above which runs a function when the variable `img` is present. But on occasions, this function does not run. Is this something to do wit the variable `img` not being stored in time? If you think this is the case, does anyone have an idea of how to delay the `.load()` call to make sure the function occurs.

Thanks

Comment: its not clear, what do you get: error or nothing?

Comment: Have you wrapped the above codes in $(document).ready()?

Comment: yes,  $(document).ready() is the 1st thing anyone does. And I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `on` method, before your `img` tags appear in the DOM:

```
$('.container img').on('load', function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/LnZTj/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you bind the event before the DOM is ready. Try putting your code in a wrapper like this:

```
//HTML
<img src="https://www.google.se/logos/2012/fencing-2012-hp.jpg">​

//JS
$(function(){
    //This will be run after DOM is loaded
    $("img").load(function(){
        alert("loaded");
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NX6Hj/